# How to remove pairs from dictionary at specific index - Swift?

Tags: swift

How to use `remove(at: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>)` to remove pairs from a dictionary in **Swift**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can obtain the index of a key/value pair in a dictionary and
then remove the entry:

```
var dict = ["foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3]
print(dict) // ["bar": 2, "baz": 3, "foo": 1]

if let idx = dict.index(forKey: "bar") {
    dict.remove(at: idx)
    print(dict) // ["baz": 3, "foo": 1]
}
```

However, indices  of dictionary entries are of limited use because the order of the key/value pairs in a dictionary is *unspecified,*
and inserting or deleting an entry invalidates all existing dictionary
indices.

You would achieve the
same result with

```
dict["bar"] = nil
```

or

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: "bar")
```

Those methods differ only in what they *return:*

- `dict["bar"] = nil` does not return a value.
- `dict.removeValue(forKey: "bar")` returns the removed value
  (as an optional) if the given key was present in the dictionary, and `nil` otherwise.
- `dict.remove(at: idx)` returns the removed key/value pair as a tuple.
  The return value is not optional because it takes the index of an
  existing entry as the argument.