# How can I remove whole dictionary in nested array at specific index after filter some specific value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have API response with nested array . But I can't understand how can I remove whole Dict by filtering the value .

This is the response screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0BpS.jpg

here is the json Resonse :- https://del.dog/lofavofogo.json

I have tried this but I don't know how to get filter nested value and remove whole dict at specific index

[How to remove pairs from dictionary at specific index - Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947638/how-to-remove-pairs-from-dictionary-at-specific-index-swift)

I want to remove the dict where section name are "NA"

Here is the code :-

Model Class For API Response :-

```
class filterclass: NSObject {
    var classesID : String?
    var classname : String?
    var section = [filterSections]()
    init(json: [String: Any]) {

        if let classname = json["class"] as? String {
            self.classname = classname
        }
        if let classesID = json["classesID"] as? String {
            self.classesID = classesID
        }
        print("classname",classname)
        if let evUserGoing = json["classsection"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            if  self.section.count > 0
            {
                self.section.removeAll()
            }
            for evUser in evUserGoing {
                // print("evUser",evUser)
                let userGoing = filterSections(json: evUser)

                self.section.append(userGoing)

            }

            for sec in section {
                let section = sec.secctionname
                let setionID = sec.sectionID
            }
        }

    }
}
class filterSections: NSObject {
    var sectionID : String?
    var secctionname : String?
    var isSelctedSection : Bool = false
     init(json: [String: Any]) {
        if let sectionID = json["sectionID"] as? String {
            self.sectionID = sectionID
        }
        if let secctionname = json["section"] as? String {
            self.secctionname = secctionname
        }

         print("sectioname",secctionname)
    }
}
```

API POST Method TO hit API :-

```
func getClassSectionAPI()  {
        if ReusableClass.sharedInstance.isNetworkAvailable() == true
        {
            ReusableClass.sharedInstance.showActivityIndicator()
            let UUid = LoginUserInfo.sharedInstance.uuid!

            let dictionary = ["uuid":UUid,"device_id":devicetoken,"school_id":LoginUserInfo.sharedInstance.schoolId!, "user_type":LoginUserInfo.sharedInstance.usertype!]
             print(dictionary)
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(dictionary) {
                if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                    //  print(jsonString)
                    let cipher:String = CryptoHelper.encrypt(input:jsonString)!;
                    let NewEncryption = "data=\(cipher)"
                     print(NewEncryption)
                    let hmac_md5 = cipher.hmac(algorithm: .sha512, key: kHMACKey)
                    print("hmac",hmac_md5)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(hmac_md5, forKey: Headerkey)
                    Singleton.sharedInstance.getWebservicesverify(params: NewEncryption, Methodname: KFilterClassSection, data: Stringnil)
                    { (result) in

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            ReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
                        }
                        if result != nil
                        {
                            do {
                                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result)
                                if let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                                    let Dict = function.convertToDictionary(text: json)! as NSDictionary
                                    guard let data = Dict[KData] as? String
                                        else
                                    {
                                        return
                                    }

                                    self.baseDict = data

                                }
                            }
                            catch {
                            }
                            guard  let output = CryptoHelper.decrypt(input:self.baseDict)
                                else
                            {
                                return
                            }
                            print(output)
                            let mainDict = function.convertToDictionary(text: output)! as NSDictionary
                            let status = mainDict[KStatus]  as! NSInteger
                            if(status == 1)
                            {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    print("Main dict",mainDict)
                                    guard let messageArray = mainDict["data"] as? [[String: Any]] else{

                                        return
                                    }

                                    if self.arrayClasSection.count > 0
                                    {
                                        self.arrayClasSection.removeAll()
                                    }
                                      print("Main dict",messageArray)
                                    for arr in messageArray {
                                        let obj = filterclass.init(json: arr)

                                        if let index = self.arryFilterTemperary.index(where: { $0.classname == obj.classname  }) {
                                           // let filtered = self.arryFilterTemperary.filter { $0.classname == "NA" }
                                            obj.section = self.arryFilterTemperary[index].section
                                            self.arrayClasSection.append(obj)

                                            for sec in self.arryFilterTemperary[index].section {
                                                let section = sec.sectionID
                                                let sectionName = sec.secctionname
                                                self.NASection = sec.secctionname!
                                                print(self.NASection)
                                                self.selectedNASectionID = sec.sectionID!

//                                                let test = self.arryFilterTemperary[index].section.filter { !$0.value.contains("") }
//                                                print(test)
                                            }



                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                          self.arrayClasSection.append(obj)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
                                    self.tableFilter.reloadData()
                                }

                            }
```

> I want to append the data to array but before appending I want to
>   filter that "NA" value dict from the array

Comment: so you want to remove the whole dictionary which include the NA value ?

Comment: why you are pasting the code if it will not help? it would be better if you pasted the JSON Format and described briefely what you want the desired output to be

Comment: @basilisk yes sir

Comment: here is the json format :- https://del.dog/lofavofogo.json

Comment: Please post your JSON in indented form, the linearised form makes it hard for your readers to figure out what you are up to.

Once you use the Decodable protocol to decode your JSON it should become pretty obvious to filter for a value. If that still does not help you should try to stay your problem more clearly.

Comment: @Patru Corrected json format now check again https://del.dog/lofavofogo.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is your first question I go to some greater length in answering it than usual. Playgrounds are an exceptional way to demonstrate your problem, so you should always try to compose your questions in a form of one. I will post my answer directly from the Playground I have done.

With that out of the way lets get to the question. Your main problem seems to be that you tried an ill fated `JSONSerialization` "shortcutt" route. This looks cheap from the outside, but working with the unavoidable optionality of a `[String:Any]` comes at a high cost in a language like Swift. The way to go is the brilliant `Codable` protocol, at least in my opinion. Once you define your data structure properly Xcode has so much more possibilities to guide you through the APIs that writing your filter code becomes a piece of cake.

Enough of the ranting, let's get to the pizza.

```
import UIKit

let dataStr = """
{
    "status":1,
    "message":"Class and sections list",
    "data":[
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"A",
                    "sectionID":"1",
                    "classesID":"1"
                },
                {
                    "section":"B",
                    "sectionID":"3",
                    "classesID":"1"
                }
            ],
            "class":"First",
            "classesID":"1"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"A",
                    "sectionID":"2",
                    "classesID":"2"
                },
                {
                    "section":"B",
                    "sectionID":"7",
                    "classesID":"2"
                }
            ],
            "class":"Second",
            "classesID":"2"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"A",
                    "sectionID":"20",
                    "classesID":"15"
                }
            ],
            "class":"Third",
            "classesID":"15"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"NA",
                    "sectionID":"33",
                    "classesID":"22"
                }
            ],
            "class":"Pre Nursery",
            "classesID":"22"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"NA",
                    "sectionID":"34",
                    "classesID":"23"
                },
                {
                    "section":"A",
                    "sectionID":"35",
                    "classesID":"23"
                },
                {
                    "section":"B",
                    "sectionID":"36",
                    "classesID":"23"
                },
                {
                    "section":"C",
                    "sectionID":"37",
                    "classesID":"23"
                }
            ],
            "class":"Fourth four",
            "classesID":"23"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"NA",
                    "sectionID":"38",
                    "classesID":"24"
                }
            ],
            "class":"Fifth",
            "classesID":"24"
        },
        {
            "classsection":[
                {
                    "section":"NA",
                    "sectionID":"39",
                    "classesID":"25"
                }
            ],
            "class":"sixth 6th",
            "classesID":"25"
        }
    ]
}
"""

struct Section: Codable {
    let section, sectionId, classesId: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sectionId = "sectionID"
        case classesId = "classesID"
        case section
    }
}

struct Class1: Codable {
    let classsection: [Section]
    let clazz, classesId: String
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case classsection
        case clazz = "class"
        case classesId = "classesID"
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let data: [Class1]

    func filterSections(notMatching filterVal: String) -> Response {
        let filteredData = data.map { (clazz) -> Class1 in
            let filteredSections = clazz.classsection.filter { (sect) -> Bool in
                sect.section != filterVal
            }
            return Class1(classsection: filteredSections, clazz: clazz.clazz, classesId: clazz.classesId)
        }
        return Response(status: status, message: message, data: filteredData)
    }
}

let jsonData = dataStr.data(using:.utf8)!

do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)

    let filteredResponse = res.filterSections(notMatching: "NA")

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    print(String(data:try encoder.encode(filteredResponse), encoding: .utf8)!)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

As you can see your data structure is easily defined and the filtering code is really easy to understand once you wrap your head around the lambdas (which you should). The playground will output nicely formatted JSON as an answer, this way it is easy to check that your code does the right thing without all the messy parts of asynchronous communication (which are still nicely done in Swift).

Here's my last tipp of the day: Always try to isolate your problem as much as possible if you post a question on StackOverflow. I think your question carried too much legacy, you should whittle it down for the next one. This will improve your chances for a quick answer.

Comment: Thanx for the perfect answer sir and to guide me on writing better questions for the future problems . I am thankful to you :-)